# How to categorize/classify numbers from different ranges using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, multiple-conditions

I want to categorize numbers from **[0:15]** into **5** classes: `A, B, C, D, E, F`

**Rules:**

```
0-1: Class A
2-4: Class B
5-7: Class C
8-10: Class D
11-13: Class E
14-15: Class F
```

**Explanation:** if number is in range **[0:1]** then it will be classified as **A**; if a number is in **[2:4]** class is **B**, and so on.

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

---

I know it can be done with multiple `IFs`, but I have trouble figuring out what a formula will look like, epsecially distinguishing different number ranges.

Comment: Use VLOOKUP.  create a table with the minimums in one column and the class in another.  Then use VLOOKUP with the forth criterion as true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using nested `IFs` - I'm generally opposed to that method on moral grounds anyway, but it's also difficult to maintain. I'd suggest using either a `VLOOKUP` or an `INDEX(MATCH` structure.

We'll take your example of the rules and modify it slightly:

```
Min |  Class
--------------
0   |  Class A
2   |  Class B
5   |  Class C
8   |  Class D
11  |  Class E
14  |  Class F
```

Now, assuming your Max values are in sheet 2, column A, we'll use the following formula in the Class column of your output:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$7,2,TRUE)
```

This has the advantage of being much easier to maintain and clearer to read.

Comment: Very true, my brain got mashed and I was thinking of MATCH. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

```
=MID("AABBBCCCDDDEEEFF",A1+1,1)
```

or

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,2,5,8,11,14,16;"A","B","C","D","E","F",""})
```

or this hacky version

```
=CHAR((A1+1)/3+65)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a <strike>long</strike> IFS with several similar conditions, however here it is:

```
=IFS(A2<2,"A",A2<5,"B",A2<8,"C",A2<11,"D",A2<14,"E",A2<16,"F‌​")
```

Comment: You do not need the AND()s.  Because of how IF resolves it needs to only be `=IF(A2<2,"A",IF(A2<5,"B",IF(A2<8,"C",IF(A2<11,"D",IF(A2<11,"E","F")))))`

Comment: Also a comment on the fact that `IFS` is only available in Office 265 Excel and not earlier versions.

Comment: The IFS version that is shorter without the AND(), `=IFS(A2<2,"A",A2<5,"B",A2<8,"C",A2<11,"D",A2<14,"E",A2<16,"F")`